# UIScreen.main.brightness rarely gives an inaccurate value when used in applicationDidEnterBackground in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, brightness

I'm trying to detect screen lock in iphone with swift code `UIScreen.main.brightness` value to get current brightness of screen. I am using it inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.

At lock screen (by pushing lock button), brightness value is 0.0 and at pushing app to background (by pushing home button) the value of brightness is greater than zero.

95% of the times results are good however there occurs some instances when brightness value on lock screen is greater than zero. Maybe because inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` the value of brightness is calculated before screen is actually locked in rare occasions.
Does anyone know how to handle this situation gracefully?

Comment: followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071009/can-we-detect-whether-a-user-left-through-the-home-button-or-lock-button-without

But it only allows me to run the else block only no matter if I press home button or lock button.