# Can I detect whether a user left through the home button or lock button in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift

before ios 14, I can detect by UIScreen.main.brightness ([Can we detect whether a user left through the home button or lock button without listening to darwin notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071009/can-we-detect-whether-a-user-left-through-the-home-button-or-lock-button-without?answertab=active#tab-top))

But now it doesn't work.

Can I detect whether a user left through the home button or lock button in iOS 14?

Comment: Probably not. This was always an unsupported hack.

Comment: But some of apps in appstore can detect