# How to differentiate between locked state and background state of app in swift iOS17?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

The requirement is to differentiate between these two states:

1. Firstly when the app was opened and user presses the lock button and mobile is locked and app went into the background.
2. Secondly when the app was opened and user presses the home button or swipes it up and app went into the background but the phone remains unlocked.

In both these cases app goes into the background so cannot detect whether it went to the background using the lock button or simple home button is swiped up.

I tried a combination of these 3 app lifecycle methods in AppDelegate.swift file to detect if the app goes to the background by pressing the lock button or the home button is swiped up:

1. applicationWillResignActive
2. applicationDidBecomeActive
3. applicationDidEnterBackground

Initializing these 3 flag variables to false in application function inside AppDelegate.swift:

```
let willResignActive = UserDefaults.standard
let didBecomeActive = UserDefaults.standard
let didEnterBackground = UserDefaults.standard
willResignActive.set(false, forKey: "willResignActive")
didBecomeActive.set(false, forKey: "didBecomeActive")
didEnterBackground.set(false, forKey: "didEnterBackground")
```

This is my AppDelegate.swift file code:

```
import UIKit
import Capacitor

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let willResignActive = UserDefaults.standard
    let didBecomeActive = UserDefaults.standard
    let didEnterBackground = UserDefaults.standard
    willResignActive.set(false, forKey: "willResignActive")
    didBecomeActive.set(false, forKey: "didBecomeActive")
    didEnterBackground.set(false, forKey: "didEnterBackground")
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App will resign active!")
    let willResignActive = UserDefaults.standard
    willResignActive.set(true, forKey: "willResignActive")
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App did enter background!")
    let didEnterBackground = UserDefaults.standard
    didEnterBackground.set(true, forKey: "didEnterBackground")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App did become active!")
    let didBecomeActive = UserDefaults.standard
    didBecomeActive.set(true, forKey: "didBecomeActive")
}

}
```

Assuming if any of these three lifecycle methods is not being called in either of the two scenerios (Lock Button Pressed or the Home Button Pressed) then I can detect the difference. But as all of the above functions executed in both the cases so all the 3 flags were set to true because of which I could not differentiate if the app went to the background using the lock button or the home button!

Comment: The app is actually created in ionic cross-platform in which there is a capacitor plugin named AndroidCheckLock written in Swift language in which I want to detect the locked state or background state of the app!

Comment: You could check `UIApplication.shared.state` it passes through `.inactive` if the "App Switcher" appears, but not if the phone is directly locked in my tests... On the Background to Foreground, it passes through active though. So there is some logical state to follow to detect (not just the presence of one, but rather a following of states to determine what did the user do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071009/can-we-detect-whether-a-user-left-through-the-home-button-or-lock-button-without

Comment: I could not even find the solution for it, but there must be some way, as the Pocket Points student app is doing the same thing.

Comment: You may be able to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622925-protecteddataavailable) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationprotecteddatawillbecomeunavailable) with the caveat that it won't work if the phone doesn't have content protection enabled (ie there is no passcode set)

Comment: Yes @Paulw11, this works but only if there is a Passcode or Face Id is enabled